# Apply template to a sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the PnP approach for getting the publishing site template and creating a new sitecollection and applying the template so that i get the replica of the source site.

I am getting the error- Scope of template does not match target while running 
the below powershell script to apply the template -
$web="https://shareptdev.sharepoint.com/sites/newpub/replicasite 
$templateFile = "E:\Path\template.xml";
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Web $web -Path $templateFile

Answer (score 0):

The variable **$web** must be your site context must use the **Get-PnPWeb** on the connected site. Something like this:

```
$siteUrl = "https://shareptdev.sharepoint.com/sites/newpub/replicasite"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
$web = Get-PnPWeb

$templateFile = "E:\Path\template.xml"
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Web $web -Path $templateFile
```

Comment: Also see https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1574